# Changing a file on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine Python project that I haven't touched since 2014, when you worked with a desktop app to upload and deploy it. Google App engine changed a lot in the meantime. According to the information the [deploying guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/uploading-resources) I copy
the file(s) like this:

```
gsutil cp main.py gs://myproject.appspot.com/
```

I converted my app.yaml file to a json file using their utility. When I initially deployed the app using [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/create) it failed because there was no deployment information, so I added this:

```
  "deployment": {
    "files": {
      "main": {
        "sourceUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/myproject/main.py"
      },
    }
  },
```

However when I deployed again I got an error because it couldn't find the file with that URL. The gsutil has to use a bucket with gs://something and the file has to exist at https:// something. How can I upload the file to the project and specify the location in the app.json file?

Comment: Take care, that's just deployment using the Admin API. The typical GAE deployment method is https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/uploadinganapp#deploying_an_app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably using what is now called App Engine Standard environment.  Deploys are handled with the `gcloud app deploy` command.

Example:

```
gcloud app deploy --version [YOUR_VERSION_ID] --no-promote --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]
```

Here is more info for [Deploying a Python App](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/uploadinganapp)

The deploy command uses [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) file for configuration info.